# How to convert such file into actual image for upload

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, monaca

Hi guys Im trying to upload an image from camera capture on Cordova and sending to PHP file.
The images sent to the PHP file comes like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///data/user/0/mobi.monaca.debugger/cache/1650991444040.jpg
```

How do I save this as actual image file on my server?

Thanks

Comment: You don't, because whatever is trying to upload the file is not working correctly. It's sending the local file path instead of any actual data. You must first fix the issue at the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, it was true as Sammitch pointed out, I wasn't sending the local file.

I now solved it this way:

```
function onSuccess(imageData) { 
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage'); 
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData; 
      var file = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      $(".image-tag").val(file);
      $('#plswait').html('Please wait...');
      var wait=setTimeout("document.sendcapture.submit();",5000);
   }
```

I have a HTML form that collects and sends the data to my PHP file, like so

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sendcapture" name="sendcapture" action="https://.....com/saveUploadImg" style="text-align: center;">  
     <input type="text" name="image" class="image-tag">     
</form>
         

 <div style="text-align: center;">
<button class="btn btn-success" id = "cameraTakePicture">CAPTURE WITH CAMERA</button>
<img style="display: none;" id = "myImage"></img>
<br>
<div id="plswait" style="color: red; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;"></div>
```